# Ember get data from the store

Tags: ember.js, model, store

I'm stuck with a very basic thing in Ember.. I try to setup a model were I save some information from the login and I want to use it after that on a different page.

Example: mysite.com/ (login form) => mysite/home (homepage where I want to display some information from the / with my model)

I've did this so far :

in my App.LoginController :

```
var login = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: host,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            accepts: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) {
                login.reset();
                console.log("DEBUG: Login Succeed");
                login.store.push('user', {
                    id: data.session.user.id,
                    username: data.session.user.username,
                    firstname: data.session.user.firstname,
                    lastname: data.session.user.lastname,
                    email: data.session.user.email,
                    domainid: data.session.user.domainid,
                    role: data.session.user.role,
                    status: data.session.user.status
                });
                login.transitionToRoute('home');
```

in my model :

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  domainid:   DS.attr('string'),
  email:      DS.attr('string'),
  firstname:  DS.attr('string'),
  lastname:   DS.attr('string'),
  role:       DS.attr('string'),
  status:     DS.attr('string'),
  username:   DS.attr('string')
  fullName: function(){
    return this.get('firstname') + ' ' + this.get('lastname');
  }.property('firstname', 'lastname')
});
```

and here my router :

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('login', { path: '/' });
    this.resource('home');
});

App.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('user');
    }
});
```

Edit (forgot to put my template)

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home">
<div class="group-detail">
    <div class="group-label">
        <label>Agent: {{fullName}}</label>
    </div>

    <div class="group-label">
        <label>Account: {{username}}</label>
    </div>

    <div class="group-label">
        <label>Status: {{status}}</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="enquiry link">
    {{#link-to 'enquiries'}}Enquiries{{/link-to}}
</div>
```

I saw my information saved in the ember data: Model Type : App.User

And I've those error :

```
GET http://localhost/users 404 (Not Found)
Error while loading route: undefined
```

I guess this must be obvious, but I don't know.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I must say as well that I tried to use this.store.all('user') I don't have any error, but I don't get anything from it... Its weird because I can see the entry with the ember debugger ?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured something out, but I don't think its the most prettiest way to do it..

For my Template I've used the {{#each}} to display the information from the store :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home">
    {{#each}}
    <div class="group-detail">
        <div class="group-label">

            <label>Agent: {{fullName}}</label>

        </div>

        <div class="group-label">
            <label>Account: {{username}}</label>
        </div>

        <div class="group-label">
            <label>Status: {{status}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
    <div class="enquiry link">
        {{#link-to 'enquiries'}}Enquiries{{/link-to}}
    </div>

</script>
```

And for the App.HomeRoute I used the store.all('user') :

```
App.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.all('user');
    }
});
```

So... its working, but is it possible to get the only one user from the store and to display it without the each ??

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a few months old, but I think this is how you can fix your page:

In your App.LoginController, do the following:

```
login.transitionToRoute('home', data.session.user.id);
```

In your Router do:

```
this.resource('home', { path: ':user_id' });
```

In your Route do:

```
model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
}
```

That should do the trick I believe.